# How to run oracle enterprise manager?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I cannot run OEM in my system, it gives page not found error. My Oracle version is 10g. Can someone please guide me how to run it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you start it with emcontrol?

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/emctl start dbconsole
```

When this succeeded, it prints you the url where EM is listening for connections; usually http://dbhost:1158/em

Comment: When I run that it give following output.                       Oracle Enterprise Manager 10g Database Control Release 10.2.0.1.0
Copyright (c) 1996, 2005 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
chathurag-PC.IronOne.Local:1158/em/console/aboutApplication
Starting Oracle Enterprise Manager 10g Database Control ...The requested service has already been started.                          I tried with http://chathurag-PC.IronOne.Local:1158/em Now it gives Unable to connect msg in firefox

Comment: So this runs already - then go to http://chathurag-PC.IronOne.Local:1158/em and log in ..

Comment: Now it gives Unable to connect msg in firefox

Comment: If you access that from a remote machine, a firewall may be in your way(?)

Comment: no I'm run it in same machine. I cannot telnet to port 1158 but I can telnet to port 8080 where the tomcat server is running. Cannot find where is the problem

Comment: Stop it and start it again.  It will tell you what port it's running on.  I think it goes to like 5500 if 1158 was already configured.  You may have to just redo the configuration from scratch if it got messed up.  That's not hard to do but requires a short period of exclusive database access, so you usually can't do it on a live DB.

Comment: Yehhh. Redoing the process got secceeded. Thanks Heiko and JOTN for your help

Answer (score 1):

first write in terminal

```
emctl start dbconsole
```

then go your browser and write localhost:1158/em